# How to get info from Xpages error log

Tags: jvm, xpages

The following message can be found in the server log in the file system on the Domino server:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.encodeEnd(UIDataPanelBase.java:280)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:856)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:641)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:320)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:335)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:219)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
>       at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:583)
>       at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
>       at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:860)
>       at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:803)
>       at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:572)
>       at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
>       at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:658)
>       at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:481)
>       at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
>       at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
>       at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)

Is there any way to get more info about the error? If there is, how to get more details?

Comment: Could you find out which database/XPages causes the error? If not, setting a Server log level might help you: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27003598 or http://www.dominobaloney.com/2010/03/hungry-for-lotus-domino-debug-settings.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would suggest that you install the LogReader from OpenNTF.org by Jakob Majkilde (http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader). It will give you easy access to the various logfiles on the server. You may need to look at different log files for specific issues - sometimes they land in the not so obvious place ;-)

When you have installed the log reader then look at messages just after (or perhaps before) the message above. In many cases several exceptions will be thrown - and you should look for the ones that refer to your own code. Changes are that you have missed initialization of an object in your own code. If you code in Java then the logs will be even more helpful.

In addition you could (should) consider using some kind of logging mechanism in your own code to tell you how far in loading/processing a page you are before failing. You could use the XPages OpenLog Logger: http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger

/John

Comment: XPages OpenLog Logger (also incorporated in OpenNTF Domino API) will tell you, if at all possible, exactly which component is causing the NullPointerException. It's the single best piece of development I've done and has saved me countless hours of cutting code out of XPages to pinpoint the offending component.